# SCP copy windows local file to linux remote folder

Tags: linux, windows, centos, scp

How to get a file from my path d:/test.txt and copy it to /etc/var/test/test.txt?

I've tried this:

```
scp d:/test.txt /etc/var/test/test.txt
```

but that didn't work.

How do I set the hard disk from where I copy my files?

Comment: Looks like the slash after d: is the wrong way round?

Answer (score 23):

Umm, if you're using cygwin you want that command to look like

```
scp /cygdrive/d/test.txt <linux ip>:/etc/var/test/test.txt
```

Or you can use WinSCP, you'll probably find that simpler.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to copy files from Windows to Linux using the command line is through pscp. It is very easy and secure. For pscp to work on your windows machine, you need it add its executable to your systems path. Once it is done, you can use the following format to copy the file.

```
pscp -pw password D:\test.txt user@192.168.33.10:/etc/var/test/test.txt
```

You can refer the following blog post for more information on pscp setup.

http://comtechies.com/2016/02/copy-files-between-windows-and-linux.html

Comment: To improve your answer, I suggest you include some relevant quotes / summary in your answer ...  (leaving the hyperlink in it is fie, eg for those who want more background info, etc)

Comment: is it possible to tar a directory on linux and send it to windows using pscp?

Answer (score 8):

to copy a file from **windows** to **linux** write:

```
scp -i privatekey pathFileOnWindows user@publicIp:pathDirectoryLinux
```

(the colon **:** is important!)

Example:

//I am located here in my console

```
C:\Users\oscar>
```

//I'm executing the next command

```
scp -i C:\Users\oscar\Documents\llaves\ubuntu.pem C:\Users\oscar\Documents\index.html ubuntu@ec2-54-94-247-176.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/
```

You can puth the full path or location in the path where the file is located. `~/` means the home directory of the user `ubuntu`

Comment: In 2020 PowerShell now has scp available without having to install anything else

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are on Windows, best way is to download and install cygwin. Get the path to the binary folder and add it to the system path. You can now run Linux commands on your command line.

Open the command prompt and go to the directory where your file is that you want to copy. Run the following command;

```
scp file.txt root@1.1.1.1:/opt/
```

- scp - secure copy command
- file.txt - file you want to copy
- root - username used to log onto CentOS machine
- 1.1.1.1 - IP address of CentOS machine. Needless to say your Windows machine and the CentOS machine have to be able to communicate with one another
- :/opt - This is the directory with which you save the file to, I generally save everything to the /opt directory
- Don't forget the @ between the username and IP Address and the : between the IP Address and directory you are saving the file to

If you need a key to login into the server, enter the following;

```
scp key.pem file.txt root@1.1.1.1:/opt
```

For handiness sake I just copy the file I want to copy across to the key file directory, that way you know everything will run smoothly

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend to use WinSCP if you're a **Windows user**. It has a good intuitive interface and gets the job done easily and with no pain.

[Download link](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the remote machine:

```
scp user@hostname:D:\text.txt user@hostname:/etc/var/test/test.txt
```

If you are currently on Windows machine:

```
winscp D:\text.txt user@hostname:/etc/var/test/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install any ssh client (OpenSSH) which support command line interface for your windows machine:

And add its path to windows Variable:

My Windows System output like below:

[image]

Then you will able to execute the same commands on your windows machine

You can copy also complete directory by executing:

```
scp -r path/to/dir_name/* user@remote-ip:/path/to/destination_dir
```

To Copy Single File:

```
scp -r path/to/file_name.zip user@remote-ip:/path/to/destination_dir/
```

Replace the file extension with your own file.

Answer (score 1):

pscp with -pw exposes my password, which I don't like.  The below answer works just like me using scp on linux -> linux.

```
pscp -scp C:\Windows\foo.txt username@10.0.0.1:/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP is definitely an useful utility, especially if you want a graphic interface. But if you're looking for a command line alternative without having to deal with installing cygwin, there's also `pscp` which is part of the PuTTY collection of tools.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows and want to copy to the linux server then install the WINSCP and just use the drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH is available for PowerShell since 2019.  Instructions for installation are available from Microsoft's [Docs site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).  Instructions for use of OpenSSH utilities are available on OpenSSH [project site](https://www.openssh.com/).

Basically, once you install the OpenSSH suite, scp will work as you are accustomed.

```
scp user@source:path/to/source/file user@destination:path/to/target/file
```

where source and destination are hostnames or IP addresses and a path and filename without a host name/address will be treated as local.

Answer (score 0):

```
SCP <path of the file along with filename and extension> <name of vm>@<ip address>:<path where file needs to be copied>
```